# PowerShell Script after install

Tags: inno-setup

Newbie question: I would like to run a powershell script (.ps1) at the end of the inno-setup install. Can anyone give me a tip on where to put this? I want the user prompted to be asked if he wants to run this script.

Oh yes, what this script does is run netsh.exe to open up a port, the script is clever and it grabs Env:username and Env:userdomain from the current context. Would the context be the admin who is running the setup? or would it be the original user that ran the setup.exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Run]
.....; Description: Run Script; Flags: postinstall
```

(See the help for more details.)  By default this will display a checkbox and run under the original user's context (although it depends a bit on how the installer is run).

You might want to reconsider this approach, though; if you are performing a machine-wide install then you should probably open the port machine-wide too.  You can do this with pure Inno code calling WinAPIs -- no powershell required.  (Which is a good thing, because it might not be installed.)

Alternatively if you want to keep it a per-user setting you should consider making your application prompt the user for a decision on first run.  After all, why give an option to only one of the many possible users of your app?

Comment: A very good point. But in this case, our users like the security of restricting who can open up a port to a single user. I note that InstallShield has allowing PowerShell script as part of setup. INHO: It would be great if inno setup removed the Pascal and went with integrated powershell for vista, win7 and up installs.

Comment: Well, you're free to suggest that at the official Inno suggestions site.  But I doubt it'd get a lot of traction as Inno is itself written in Pascal.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to run the script using the `ShellExec` from the code.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "yourPowershell.ps1"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: overwritereadonly replacesameversion promptifolder;

[Tasks]
Name: "runpowershell"; Description: "Do you want to run Powershell script?"

[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  ReturnCode: Boolean;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin

    if(IsTaskSelected('runpowershell')) then begin
      ExtractTemporaryFile('yourPowershell.ps1');
      ReturnCode := ShellExec('open', '"PowerShell"', ExpandConstant(' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden  -File "{tmp}\YourPowershell.ps1"'), '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);

    if (ReturnCode = False) then
        MsgBox('Message about problem. Error code: ' + IntToStr(ErrorCode) + ' ' + SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is not working. giving below error: 
Message about problem. Error code: 2 The system cannot find the file specified
Even if file is there.

Comment: Were you able to confirm that the PowerShell script was in the {tmp} directory? Is it possible that the PowerShell script itself could not find a file?

Comment: In {tmp} folder this created another folder like "is-7TUSI.tmp" and keep the .ps1  file in this folder and as soon as you close the installer it deletes the folder.

Is it possible to give one working example of inno setup which run the ps1 script without using {tmp} folder?

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is to have the PowerShell script continue to run, even after the innosetup script is completed. That is clearly not the design of the code above, which waits the innoset script until the PowerShell script is completed. So first, make sure that you really want that. If that is the case, then I would modify the code to first copy the script to the install directory, and then execute it.